# Is it normal for multiple processes of GNOME-shell to show up in top/htop?

Tags: gnome, htop

I've recently installed and started using `htop` instead of the System Monitor included in default Ubuntu installations and I noticed something weird.  I arranged htop to display the processes by memory usage and noticed I have 9 instances of GNOME-Shell running, all with different PID's.

Is this normal for GNOME?  I never noticed it before on other Ubuntu installs, but to be fair I've never looked either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are probably threads. Are they consecutive PIDs, and show up in branches under one `gnome-shell` process when you run `ps fx|grep gnome-shell`?

This is quite common when a process fork/execs or uses multiple threads.

Comment: It looks like most of them are consecutive PID's, there are a couple of them that aren't, one sits about a thousand above the others, and the last one appears and disappears, haha.  Working as usual then?

Comment: If these are threads, why do they a different process id (pid)?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka well because they are forked/execed child processes, and not pure threads in a single process.